# Как скрыть post-title в Joomla?

Tags: joomla

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, как убрать этот блок (обведен красной рамкой):
[image]

"Параметры отображения материала"->"Заголовок"->"Скрыть" не предлагать.. (не работает потому что..) 
Joomla версии 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не заголовок, а параметры отображения. Их можно настроить как в категории, так и в каждой статье отдельно (по крайней мере, так в джумле 1.7). Справа ищите блок параметры отображения.

Comment: @Vitalii Maslianok, если это не заголовок, тогда что??? Я показал на примере заголовка что ничего не работает. Может вы подскажите какую именно опцию отключить?

Comment: ну я же написал где смотреть... отключайте отображение категории, даты публикации, автора, количество просмотров, иконку печати, иконку пдф и т.д.

Comment: при редактировании материала справа должен быть блок "Опции отображения" или както так. Поклацайте, по памяти очень сложно сказать...

Comment: ![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/gdD1i.jpg

@Vitalii Maslianok, что здесь надо отключить?

Comment: *facepalm* если ты не можешь отличить где право, а где лево, то даже за джумлу браться еще рановато.

Comment: @Vitalii Maslianok, я тебе **полный скриншот экрана** показал. Направо прокрутить не пробовал картинку?? Если у тебя проблемы с интеллектом (низкий IQ) или с браузером -- то это не значит что у всех с этим тоже плохо.

Comment: да, действительно, браузер не захотел показывать полную картинку. при таких условиях все должно быть ок.

Comment: Еще вспомнил, что в менеджере материалов, вверху справа есть кнопка Параметры. Можно там покопать.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Теперь все получилось.